# Can't open IDW interpolation while I'm using QGIS 3.34

Tags: qgis, interpolation, tin

I can't open IDW and TIN interpolation. How can I solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: Error seems to come when the process is calculating the pixel size. What kind of source data do you have? Do you see any problem with the extent of that dataset?

Comment: Please add the error(s) as a (formatted) text. The images can't be displayed in some devices. Moreover, you need to add more details about your data, such as what is the CRS, from where did you obtained them etc.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is due to a [bug](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/55138) in QGIS version 3.34.0, which you are probably using. The issue has been already [fixed](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/55211) and it doesn't occur using the latest available QGIS version 3.34.1 or QGIS version 3.28.13.